# dispatch_after is persisting view controller in memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, memory, dispatch

I have this code, which runs a block of code after a delay.

```
public func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

The problem is that the view controller using the delay function persists even after dismissal. With the code removed, it becomes nil, as it should.

I need to know how to have a delay function, like this, but which wouldn't persist the object it was called from, and instead would just not call the block, in the event that it's otherwise no longer existent.

This is in Swift, but replies in Objective-C are entirely appreciated.

Comment: Show us the code of your `closure`. Typically, you have to solve retain cycles using `weak` references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, as others have pointed out, is that you are probably calling this function from the view controller, but have a reference to `self`, which captures that view controller and keeps a strong reference to it.

So, let's say you did something like this from your view controller class:

```
delay(5) {
    self.label.hidden = true
    return
}
```

You would replace that with something that explicitly says that it should maintain `weak` reference to `self`:

```
delay(5) { [weak self] in
    self?.label.hidden = true
    return
}
```

Note, I had to unwrap the optional `self`, when I used it. In this example, I used optional chaining to ensure this fails gracefully if `self` is `nil` by the time the closure is called.

Answer (score 1):

If you use your ViewController in closure then it is normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you refer to self in your closure. When you do that, the block keeps a strong reference to the object

If the object also keeps a strong reference to the block/closure then you get a retain cycle.

However, in your case, the block/closure should only be retained until the dispatch_after() call fires. (I believe the strong reference to the block/closure is held by the dispatch queue, and released after the task is completed and removed from the queue.)